# PHP Arrays Information

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hi all I am developing web app using **php, jquery and bootstrap**. Now in this app what i am doing is that i am getting a **value** from button on button click event and passing the value to the ajax, jquery and then jquery to the php file where it will be processed and this value is stored in an **array**. Every time new value comes value is passed through jquery and then to php where the value is **pushed** in array. Now let's assume that i have **refreshed** the page, will my array will be **empty** on page refresh or it will hold the value in that php file. The structure of files is like **HTML/CSS** file containing the form, jquery file containing all the jquery functions and php file processing the data. If html page gets refreshed will the array become empty or not ... ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Every time you call the php file the array is empty ... for "remeber the array content" you need store the value of php ... in db or in session var or in localstorage (client side ) for preserve the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php array will be empty and/or will only ever have one value in it.

This is because each request via ajax will be a new request, which is asynchronous, to the current request.

A solution would be to store the array in the PHP file in a session, and retrieve the array from the session.

That way the data will persist across multiple requests.